# jquery/prototype conflicts in Magento

Tags: jquery, magento

This is a Magento store based on the Acumen theme from Themeforest.

Seemingly out of the blue, jquery stuff is now not working. Acumen has jquery loading through a magento static block and none of that has been touched.

Yesterday I was working on adding the jquery.clearfield.js plugin to add that functionality to our forms. I wasn't modifying core files. I loaded the clearfield plugin through another static block and added that static block to our contact CMS page.

I was logged in at the time and was getting the logged in values for name/email populating automatically, and at some point I logged out as a customer to test the field values when not logged in.

I was unable to login because of the jquery conflicts. I've gone through the code, I can't seem to find anything that's changed that would be causing this, and I hadn't modified any core or theme files.

If you view source/inspect element on any of the pages, you'll see the prototype and jquery error messages.

Any thoughts/insight would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Edited to remove old dev site URL (plus, I no longer work there, so kinda tacky to have that here still)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to include the jquery and no conflict code in your local.xml then use:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Cheers!!

---

Revision 2: You will probably want to edit the page.xml and insert the jquery.js and noConflict in there, as page.xml is loaded before local.xml.  Or, you can use local.xml to remove all of the previous Prototype js calls, then re-add them.  I found editing page.xml to be easier.

Also, I had trouble getting Action setText to work for the "var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();", so I created a separate js file with that line by itself.  Not great, but it is loaded right after the main jQuery js file is loaded (and before Prototype)

Answer (score 4):

**Update: Don't use this anymore, refer to the answer by @MagePsycho above.**

---

This isn't a matter of jQuery and Prototype conflicting, but rather of jQuery actually not having loaded yet when you call jQuery.noConflict().

In your source, the "jQuery.noConflict()" call is right in the head, but jQuery itself gets loaded at the very end of the page (below the footer) via the google api.

My suggestion would be to abandon the google api, load jQuery locally via XML by

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.x.x.min.js</name></action>
```

and embed a jQuery.noConflict() call right before the end of jquery-1.x.x.min.js itself.

Comment: Ok, that helped some. I forgot that this theme is using a jquery load as well as a jquery run script, both set up as static blocks. I've placed both scripts in page.xml of our theme and things seem to be sort of working. Product page JS is working properly, but the login page button still isn't working. I have my suspicions as to why.

Answer (score 1):

When running jQuery and Prototype together you need to run "no conflict" mode. This re-maps jQuery's hook from "$" to "jQuery", allowing Prototype to continue to use "$".

If the plug-in us using "$", it's going to be using Prototype's function and will likely crash. You may need to manually edit the plugin and replace "$" with "jQuery".

Comment: noConflict is already being called. The weird thing is, I haven't touched any of that, it just started showing up and on pages that have no idea the clearfield plugin is being used. I've even gone back and undone the changes I've made and the errors are still showing.For example, see page http://dev.thehipster.com.au/wink-nyc/april-blouse . It's showing jquery as not defined.

Comment: I don't think you have noconflict set up properly. There's still $ code that jQuery is using. Vire source on that URL and you'll see it neat the bottom of the page: $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.button_sizechart, #close-size-chart').click(function(e) {

Comment: I feel like this explains the jQuery/$ better and the issue that is actually happening, so I gave you an up