# how to use jQuery in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento extension development.

In my code i want to be a call jQuery function when i am click on button.

I add `jquery.js` in js folder of magento.

My jQuery code is:-

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#stage').css("visibility", "hidden");                  
    jQuery("#save").click(function() {
    var street = document.getElementById('street_1').value;
    var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
    var state=document.getElementById('region').value;       
    var zip=document.getElementById('zip').value;
    var newcity=document.getElementById('newcity').value;
    document.getElementById('city').value=newcity;
    jQuery('#city').hide();
    alert("In POst");

    return true;
}
</script>
```

and my button attributes is:

```
<input type="submit" name="truemagentosubmit" value="This will real submit the form" onclick='changeText2()' id="save"/>
```

so why doesn't it work?. what wrong in this?
when am click on button it not call function of jQuery.

please suggest some solution. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a prototype/jquery `$` collision, see [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7532124/693207

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax errors are in your code. click and document ready functions are not closed properly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#save").click(function() {
      var street = document.getElementById('street_1').value;
      var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
      var state=document.getElementById('region').value;       
      var zip=document.getElementById('zip').value;
      var newcity=document.getElementById('newcity').value;
      document.getElementById('city').value=newcity;
      jQuery('#city').hide();
      alert("In POst");
      return true;
    });
}); //jQuery Proper closing
```

Answer (score 0):

place your js file in skin/js folder. and call that js file from getSkinUrl() function in your phtml file. i hope this may helpful for you.
or  you may got any jquery conflict with prototype.js